# Fizzy with no head?

Tags: carbonation, first-time-brewer, small-batch, over-carbonation

My recent brew (#2) is well carbonated, but has little head to it when poured (and what's there dissipates quickly). Is it over carbonated? Too much priming sugar?

Also, I am used to seeing a strong head on bottled craft brews from the store, so does the amount of head mean anything about the brew itself?

**Homebrew #2**:

- [American Wheat 1 Gallon Extract Recipe Kit](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/cascade-wheat-1-gallon-recipe-kit.html)
- Conditioned with [Fizz Drops](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/nb-fizz-drops-8-oz.html) for ~ 2 1/2 weeks
- 1 drop per 12-16 oz bottle, 2 drops per 22 oz / 750mL bottle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your glass is totally clean and free from oils and detergent. I doubt the beer lost it's head because of overcarbonation (and I don't think you've overcarbonated.) Even if you did, wheat beers tend to be served with medium-high to high levels of carbonation.

The head stability is produced from proteins and hop acids. Looking at the recipe in the kit, there should be plenty of each - especially so being a wheat beer. So, I'd check the glass to make sure it's completely clean and free from oils and soaps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to do a good clean/rinse before my next pour.

Comment: In emphasis, detergents such as dish soap are notorious for leaving residual oils on plastic and other surfaces, which will most certainly effect head retention.  The importance of thorough rinsing cannot be understated.